# How to make add minutes in clock picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clockpicker

I've seen this [CLOCK PICKER](http://jsfiddle.net/weareoutman/YkvK9/) example and I notice that the minutes is in 5 minutes interval. I would like to make it a 1 minute interval each so I can choose what I want. So for example is `10:32` like that. But how do i edit it?. Or it is already built for 5 minutes interval?.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<input id="input-a" value="" data-default="20:48">
<button type="button" id="button-a">Check the  minutes</button>
<button type="button" id="button-b">Check the  hours</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 var input = $('#input-a');
   input.clockpicker({
    autoclose: true
   });

  // Manual operations
   $('#button-a').click(function(e){
    // Have to stop propagation here
    e.stopPropagation();
    input.clockpicker('show')
            .clockpicker('toggleView', 'minutes');
   });
  $('#button-b').click(function(e){
    // Have to stop propagation here
    e.stopPropagation();
    input.clockpicker('show')
            .clockpicker('toggleView', 'hours');
   });
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.container {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: There does not seem to be such an option in the documentation: https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/. The only way to do it would be to change the source code.

Comment: @henmer the source code of the script?. And for the link I've seen it also

Comment: You can drag the minute hand to select in 1 minute interval.

Comment: @cagdas ow LOL I didn't that.. hahahah Thanks .. But it is possible to make it the whole 60 minutes will be appear in the clock?. Not just drag the hand?

Comment: That 5 minutes is a fixed option in the plugin, i managed to edit the source code for you but it needs a bit of fixing in UI wise have a look http://jsfiddle.net/6qq8ey33/1/ its a ll messed up though!

Comment: @BlackBurn027 yes Its hard to pick for a minute

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6qq8ey33/3/ downing the font from 14 px to 8px its some what ok!

Comment: I think u can edit the css and make it work :) :) Hope it helps.

Comment: @BlackBurn027 thanks :)

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw use http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.js instead of minified version. Try to change minute view line `for (i = 0; i < 60; i += 5)` to `for (i = 0; i < 60; i ++)`

Comment: @cagdas thats exactly what I have done! :) :)

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw Yeah i thought you wanted to display every minute on the clock itself. But yeah dragging works for just selecting any minute.

Comment: @henmer Yes in the minutes view I wanted to display every minutes. Like BlackBurn did but the first try is hard to select the time and for the second is the font is seems ok.